# How to store encrypted image in Sql server database

Tags: sql-server, image, encryption

I want to store my images on my own SQL Server database but because of security and privacy reasons, I would like to store them in encrypted format.

What is the best way to do that?

Also how to encrypt and decrypt the image for retrieval?

Actually I know the encryption methods, but my question is about using the methods in storing images on database while encrypting the images.

Comment: TDE; https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/bb934049.aspx

Comment: @AlexK. I think it is not a good solution for my question.

Comment: Why is TDE not a good solution here?

Comment: @SiavashR Why not?

Comment: Actually my problem is about images and storing them on the server not about encryption methods.

Comment: encrypt image data, insert resultant byte array into varbinary column

Comment: You said you want to encrypt the images that you store on the server. That is exactly what TDE will do for you. Not sure how that isn't relevant to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `System.Security.Cryptography` namespace . This [page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aesmanaged.aspx) has a c# example for this

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace Aes_Example
{
    class AesExample
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            try
            {

                string original = "Here is some data to encrypt!";

                // Create a new instance of the AesManaged
                // class.  This generates a new key and initialization 
                // vector (IV).
                using (AesManaged myAes = new AesManaged())
                {

                    // Encrypt the string to an array of bytes.
                    byte[] encrypted = EncryptStringToBytes_Aes(original, myAes.Key, myAes.IV);

                    // Decrypt the bytes to a string.
                    string roundtrip = DecryptStringFromBytes_Aes(encrypted, myAes.Key, myAes.IV);

                    //Display the original data and the decrypted data.
                    Console.WriteLine("Original:   {0}", original);
                    Console.WriteLine("Round Trip: {0}", roundtrip);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", e.Message);
            }
        }
        static byte[] EncryptStringToBytes_Aes(string plainText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
        {
            // Check arguments.
            if (plainText == null || plainText.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("plainText");
            if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
            if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("IV");
            byte[] encrypted;
            // Create an AesManaged object
            // with the specified key and IV.
            using (AesManaged aesAlg = new AesManaged())
            {
                aesAlg.Key = Key;
                aesAlg.IV = IV;

                // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
                ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

                // Create the streams used for encryption.
                using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                        {

                            //Write all data to the stream.
                            swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
                        }
                        encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
                    }
                }
            }


            // Return the encrypted bytes from the memory stream.
            return encrypted;

        }

        static string DecryptStringFromBytes_Aes(byte[] cipherText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
        {
            // Check arguments.
            if (cipherText == null || cipherText.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("cipherText");
            if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
            if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("IV");

            // Declare the string used to hold
            // the decrypted text.
            string plaintext = null;

            // Create an AesManaged object
            // with the specified key and IV.
            using (AesManaged aesAlg = new AesManaged())
            {
                aesAlg.Key = Key;
                aesAlg.IV = IV;

                // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
                ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

                // Create the streams used for decryption.
                using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipherText))
                {
                    using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                    {
                        using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                        {

                            // Read the decrypted bytes from the decrypting stream
                            // and place them in a string.
                            plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                        }
                    }
                }

            }

            return plaintext;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but I know encryption methods. My question is about images and storing them on the server

Comment: See this answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822520/encrypt-and-decrypt-image-net